# Symfony 2 - How to get file extension from getRequest()->files->get()

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, file-upload

I have a photo upload HTML form where its values are captured using getRequest(). How can I grab the file extension of this when I am not using Symfony forms? Here's the line I catch the form element value.

```
$image = $this->getRequest()->files->get("image");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to know the file extention you can use getClientOriginalExtension() to get the file type extention.
Like this way:

```
$image = $request->files->get( 'image' );
print_r($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
```

There are other function you can you to get other detail like file size, file type,file path and other they are

```
getATime()
getBasename()
getCTime()
getClientMimeType()
getClientOriginalExtension()
getClientOriginalName()
getClientSize()
getError()
getErrorMessage()
getExtension()
getFileInfo()
getFilename()
getGroup()
getInode()
getLinkTarget()
getMTime()
getMaxFilesize()
getMimeType()
getOwner()
getPath()
getPathInfo()
getPathname()
getPerms()
getRealPath()
getSize()
getType()
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use symfony's guessExtension() function

```
$image = $this->getRequest()->files->get("image");

// Symfony is guessing extension of file
$extension = $image->guessExtension();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$uploadPath = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../web/uploads/';

try {
    $uploadfile = $request->files->get('filename');

    /* @var $uploadfile \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File */
    $uploadedFile = $uploadfile->move($uploadPath, $uploadfile->getClientOriginalName());

    unset($uploadfile);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    /* if you don't set $avatarFile to a default file here
     * you cannot execute the next instruction.
     */
}

$filename = $uploadedFile->getBasename();
$extentison = $uploadedFile->getExtension();
```

Comment: Actually I need the file extension before uploading as I am specifying a different name and uploading the file.

Answer (score 0):

if you need get extenstion of file before upload file

This is your Entity file

```
class Excel_file_details
{
   /**
      * @var int
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      */
      private $id;

     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="filename", type="string", length=255)
     */
     private $filename;

    /**
    * Get id
    *
    * @return integer
    */
    public function getId()
    {
      return $this->id;
    }


    public function setFilename($filename)
    {
      $this->filename = $filename;

      return $this;
    }


    public function getFilename()
    {
       return $this->filename;
    }
```

}

**In your controller**

```
            $excelobj = new Excel_file_details();
            $uploaddir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../web/uploads/excelfiles/' . $folderName;
            $file = $excelobj->getFilename();
            $fileName = $excelobj->getFilename()->getClientOriginalName();
            $ext = pathinfo($uploaddir . $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $name = substr($fileName, 0, -(strlen($ext) + 1));
            $fileName = $name . '@' . date('Y-m-d H-i-s') . '.' . $ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

`getClientOriginalName()` worked for me to get the original file name. `guessEstension()` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function importFile(Request $request){
    $files = $request->files->get('image'); // Get file object
    echo $files->getClientOriginalName(); // Get File Name
    echo $files->getClientOriginalExtension(); // Get Extension
    dd($files);
}
```